# rotary encoder driver does not create device node /dev/input/eventN

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I use a board running with Linux 3.0.8.
I follow the instructions from [Documentation/input/rotary-encoder.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/rotary-encoder.txt) and call the following in driver module:

```
platform_device_register(&rotary_encoder_device);
```

The kernel prints the following when boots up:

```
[5.629682] input: rotary-encoder as /devices/platform/rotary-encoder.0/input/input1
```

and I can get this:

```
# ls /sys/devices/platform/rotary-encoder.0/input/input1/

capabilities  id            name          properties    uevent
device        modalias      phys          subsystem     uniq
```

However there is no device node `/dev/input/eventN` created.

How to fix this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd expect `udev` to create the device nodes, so I'd check if the events are correctly generated, and if there are udev rules to match it.

Comment: udev/mdev only support hotplug, right ?

Comment: No, udev pretty much creates everything in `/dev/`, no matter if hotplugged or fixed. See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev).